# how to limit the number of location with rubygeocoder gem?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, geocoding

I have a location object so location.nearbys get all the locations near location. But I want to limit the results to 5. That I am doing with location.nearbys.limit(5) , but the problem is when there are no nearby location I get an error message . It says limit cant be used on empty array [].
So, what's the solution. I can use.

```
location = location.nearbys
location = location.nearbys.limit(5) unless location.empty?
```

Do I have better ways to do this ? I am using mongoid , rails 3.0.7 , ruby 1.9.2 .

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is that rubygeocoder returns a `ActiveRecord::Relation` if successful, but an empty `Array` on failure. And Ruby's Array does not respond to `limit`, so my tip is to use `first(number)` instead of `limit(number)`, which will work with both results.

---

Found out, that the best solution of this problem is to use `take(5)` which will work both on `Mongoid::Criteria` objects and Ruby `Array`s.

Comment: it seems like first(number) does not work . It works only for array even if it is empty .

Comment: it throws wrong number of arguments (1 for 0). Which means instead of getting first n number of elements it will get a single object if I follow the exception. thanks.

Comment: Which version of Rails do you use?

Comment: I am using rails 3.0.7 , ruby 1.9.2p180 . About the answer , I think you have the closest hint for me. It should work for both array and activerecord relation.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I'm going to build a Rails app to find a solution for your problem.

Comment: many thanks. I will try out your hint in the meantime. I mean that works for both array and activerecord relation.

Comment: I am actually using mongoid. And the two classed that should support the limit/first method are Mongoid::Criteria and Array

Comment: Ah, ok. Not much experience with Mongoid. But there is always time to start something new! :)

Comment: Ok after writing the demo app, and taking my first steps with Mongoid I figured out, that `take(5)` is the best solution, without rewriting the geocoder gem. I'm adding the solution to my answer above.

Comment: thanks for your effort. I hope your effort was worthwhile , you got started with mongoid ;)

Comment: Yeah, it was worth. Mongoid is quite cool, hopefully I can use it in an upcoming Rails project. :)

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if better - but alternatively you maybe be able to wrap it in a rescue block which would also give you the option on doing something else when the result is empty

Comment: thanks . That definitely sounds better. 
location = begin
             location.nearbys.limit(5)
           rescue Exception => e
             []
           end

Comment: rescue is expensive, better use try `location.nearbys.try(:limit, 5)`

Comment: Sorry @soren but I think you don't understand the concept behind exceptions. They are definitely not an excuse for writing ugly and faulty code!

Answer (score 2):

This should work, even if you get an empty array.

```
location = location.nearbys
location = location[0..4]
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to write it would be `location.nearbys.try(:limit, 5)`

More on [Object#try](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Object.html#method-i-try)

Comment: problem with this is location.nearbys returns [] and not nil when there are no location , so [].limit will throw an exception. Thanks

Comment: just quoted from the link you have provided "if the receiving object is a nil object or NilClass". [] is not nil , its just an empty array so it won't return nil instead it will raise an exception undefined method `limit' for []:Array

Comment: @Prabesh Shrestha I apologize, you are correct. Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 0):

I believe location.nearbys is a collection. You can impose the limit on collection itself as follows:

`has_many locations, :limit => 5`

In this way you retrieve only required data from the DB and also no hassle of `rescue` or `try`.